# Postgres - Deleting attributes inside json object of json column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgres JSON column (column name = data), in which I wanted to delete all the attributes inside the JSON object.

JSON

```json
{
  "headerText": "header_text",
  "vendor": {
    "id": "some text",
    "metadata": 123123,
    "startDate": "1234234",
    "assetIds": [
      "some text"
    ],
    "endDate": "234435",
    "publishStart": 12443245,
    "publishEnd": 978128123
  },
  "footerText": "some_text"
}
```

So, here the attributes inside the `vendor` json object are dynamic, which means there may be additional attributes.

So I tried the below queries, but was unable to yield the expected result

```
1. update table_name set data = data::jsonb #- '{vendor.*}'
2. update table_name set data = data::jsonb - '{vendor.*}'::text[]
```

Expected:

```json
{
  "headerText": "header text",
  "vendor": {},
  "footerText": "some text"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace vendor with an empty value by appending it.

```
update table_name 
  set data = data || '{"vendor": {}}'
```

This requires `data` to be defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `data::jsonb || ....`

If you don't need the vendor key at all, you can also do:

```
update table_name 
  set data = data - 'vendor'
```

which completely removes the key from the value (so it results in `{"footerText": "some_text", "headerText": "header_text"}`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use concatenation to overwrite values in (postgres) json:

```
update table_name set data = data::jsonb || json_build_object('vendor', json_build_object())::jsonb
```

Comment: This is giving this error
Error - No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: sorry my bad, should work now!

Comment: If you use `jsonb_build_object()` there is no need to cast the result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is necessary because json objects can not be concatenated in postgres, thats why we need to cast into jsonString (aka jsonb), alternatively to json_build_object()::jsonb you could just use '{}'::jsonb too.

Comment: I meant: `json_build_object('vendor', json_build_object())::jsonb` can be written as `jsonb_build_object('vendor', jsonb_build_object())`